# Hooking up event handlers on a user control vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls

I tried to use this code in the form:

```
AddHandler MyControl.MouseDown, AddressOf StartDrag
```

This wont give me an error, but it doesn't happen anything when I mouse down on the Control.

the same doesn't work if I put it in the user control.

```
    Private Sub StartDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim Box = CType(sender, Control)
    Box.Tag = New DragInfo(Form.MousePosition, Box.Location)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code to `StartDrag` please. Just want to see what it's doing. Cheers.

Comment: Sure I'll do a edit to add that

Comment: Where are you calling `AddHandler MyControl.MouseDown, AddressOf StartDrag`? Is it on the Form_Load event for example?

Comment: Sorry mate, but what do you mean by "new sub"?

Comment: Every form has a  Public Sub New()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just built a user control and added it to a form. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            AddHandler UserControl1.MouseDown, AddressOf OnMouseDown
        End Sub

        Private Sub OnMouseDown (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            MessageBox.Show("sdasd")
        End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine - the messagebox appears on the screen when I press the mouse button down. I have no code at all running in the user control, so no worries about having to call RaiseEvent.

Comment: Ok i see the problem... there is a panel on the user control that covers the control

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but is that line of code ever executed?  Does StartDrag look like this:

```
Private Sub StartDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: Well yeah, I just wanted to make sure the signature was correct

Comment: What happens if you set a break point on the 'Dim Box...' line and click the mouse down?